# Get menu entries of GDBusMenuModel with PyGObject

Tags: python, dbus, pygobject, gio

So because I have the [unity-gtk-module](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-gtk-module) installed, all gtk-applications export their menu over the dbus SessionBus. My goal is to extract a list of all available menu entries. I've already implemented this with the help of pydbus, but for some reason, this solution is highly unstable and some applications just flat out crash. The unity-gtk-module uses Gio's [g_dbus_connection_export_menu_model ()](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/gio-GMenuModel-exporter.html#g-dbus-connection-export-menu-model) to export its GMenuModel modeled menu over dbus, so I thought it would make sense to try to use Gio to process the exported menu. Gio uses the [GDBusMenuModel](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/GDBusMenuModel.html) class to retrieve a menu from the bus. Python uses PyGObject for wrapping Gio:

```
from gi.repository import  Gio
connection = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SESSION, None)
menuModel = Gio.DBusMenuModel.get(connection, [bus-name e.g. ":1.5"], [object-path e.g. "/com/canonical/unity/gtk/window/0"])
```

Now menuModel should be wrapping the GMenuModel from my application. At this point I'm honestly a bit confused about how exactly the GMenuModel works (the [Description](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/GMenuModel.html) is not really helping) but it seems I have to use a [GMenuAttributeIter](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/GMenuModel.html#g-menu-model-iterate-item-attributes) object to iterate through the entries. But when I try this:

```
iter = Gio.MenuModel.iterate_item_attributes(menuModel, 0) #0 is the index of the root node
```

this happens:

```
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_menu_model_get_item_attributes: assertion 'proxy->items' failed
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: GMenuModel implementation 'GDBusMenuModel' doesn't override iterate_item_attributes() and fails to return sane calues from get_item_attributes()
```

This probably happens because GDBusMenuModel inherits GMenuModel which provides these methods, but is abstract, so GDBusMenuModel should override them, which it doesn't (see link above, it provides just g_dbus_menu_model_get ()). If this is the case, how am I supposed to actually use this class as a proxy? And if it's not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I justed logged in to SO the first time after a few years and remembered that I've actually found a solution to this question (I think). Honestly, I can't remember what half of these words even mean, but at the time I wrote a script to accomplish the task posed in the title, and as far as I remember, in the end, it worked out: https://gist.github.com/encomiastical/caa0ee955300bc2a40ef55d123b06212